# image Error builders not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

I am trying to make a list of network images. It was working until I reinstall flutter.
This is code and I tried cachedNetworkImage, and all have the same error.

```
ListTile(
  title: Text(MyNetowrk.currentChannels[index].name),
    leading: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        placeholder:'assets/images/page.png', //kTransparentImage,
        image: MyNetowrk.channels[index].icon,
        imageErrorBuilder: (context, url, error) =>
          SizedBox(width: 200, child: new Icon(Icons.error)),
     ),
   ),
),
```

This is error I got:

```
/D:/APPS/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/multi_image_stream_completer.dart:152:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/D:/APPS/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_handleAppFrame);
                     ^
/D:/APPS/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:109:29: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.

- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('/D:/APPS/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/painting/binding.dart:1
      () => PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.evict(key),
```

and it opens _network_image_io.dart file and shows line 120.

Comment: can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually did but not worked. I tried with console only, it worked

Comment: @c4m3lion, can you please elaborate. thanks in advance